# Facebook timestamps and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, timestamp

On Facebook the timestamps update themselves. If you post something, the timestamp will say, "a few seconds ago". If you keep the page open an wait a minute it will change to say, "one minute ago".

I suppose that the time objects on the page are rendering themselves every few seconds. Is there a JavaScript library that can do computations on datetime objects and produce these strings? In Python there is the datetime module and python-dateutil. Because this is client side code, how do you address templating and i18n?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[timeago, a jQuery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a library for that? It shouldn't be that complicated. Here is an example:

```
function TimeToString(var seconds) {
    if (seconds < 60)
        return seconds + " seconds ago.";
    else if (seconds < 3600) {
        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        return minutes + minutes ago.";
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now you only need to find the difference in time and post it to this function. You can then make a timer to make objects update themselves automatically every 1 minute, for example.

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

UPDATE: There seems to be a similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726/best-javascript-i18n-techniques-ajax-dates-times-numbers-currency

Comment: It'd be better to just have the timeout function set to this without any arguments, and have every element that needs time updating grabbed and updated as such. I suggest first setting the content of a "time" element to UNIX time, and parsing it on page load.

Comment: Oh, sorry. As for i18n, I don't it is that easy to do it on the client side, you would better do it on the server. Anyway for time difference, you don't really need the i18n, because the time difference will be calculated according to your server time, then you only add the difference in time on the client side. Anyway, I added a link to my answer so you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at John Resig's [prettyDate](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) .
It doesn't handle i18n though; but you can extend it.